# Defining function arguments as local variables

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I see two different ways to define default value for function arguments.
The first one is to redefine argument value like that:

```
var callName1 = function( name ) {
 name = name || 'John';
 console.log( 'Hello, ' + name );
};
```

The second one is to define local variable with the same name:

```
var callName2 = function( name ) {
 var name = name || 'John';
 console.log( 'Hello, ' + name );
}
```

Both of this methods are working the same.
So, I have two questions:
1) What's the point to define local variable with same name in the second way?
2) Which of these ways is more correct?

Comment: First one is more correct since `name` is already defined in the function and there is no need for a redefinition. On the other hand  in ES6 you can avoid both usages by the default argument values such as `var callName1 = function(name = "John") {...`

Comment: essentially there is no difference, however here is a difference when you try to convert your code with some optimizers though, making vars into lets and such, it confuses them sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between them. `var` statements for variables which are already local to the function have no effect.